# MySql LIKE operator using lastname column not working

Tags: mysql, sql

`individual` table:

```
+---------+----------+---------+------------+
| cust_id | fname    | lname   | birth_date |
+---------+----------+---------+------------+
|       1 | James    | Hadley  | 1977-04-22 |
|       2 | Susan    | Tingley | 1973-08-15 |
|       3 | Frank    | Tucker  | 1963-02-06 |
|       4 | John     | Hayward | 1971-12-22 |
|       5 | Charles  | Frasier | 1976-08-25 |
|       6 | John     | Spencer | 1967-09-14 |
|       7 | Margaret | Young   | 1951-03-19 |
|       8 | George   | Blake   | 1982-07-01 |
|       9 | Richard  | Farley  | 1973-06-16 |
+---------+----------+---------+------------+
```

Intention: find people whose last name contains `a` in the second position and an `e` anywhere after the `a`.

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM individual 
WHERE lname LIKE '_a%e';
```

Returns an empty set.

From my understanding [%](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) `matches any number of characters, even zero characters.`

Apart from a solution to this I would like to understand why my query failed and why James Hadley and Richard Farley were not returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another wildcard at the end, or it'll only match names *ending* in "e":

```
SELECT *
FROM individual 
WHERE lname LIKE '_a%e%';
```

Comment: oooooh makes sense now!